# What should be action bar's height compatible for all devices?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am using different layout for action bar and add different items to it that matched to my requirements. and then calling it in java class like this

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

It looks fine for 2 or 3 different devices but doesn't look compatible for nexus7 tablet and xhdpi. The height of action bar is small for that and it gives empty space.What should I do to manage this? I am using

```
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="48dp"
```

in actionbar layout.I have also used

```
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

but it doesn't work at all.I don't know how to fix it. Please help.

Comment: You should save a dimens.xml file in values, values hdpi, values xhdpi... and give the same name say height in all files and choose according to the pixel density. In layout file refer to that variable

Answer (score 0):

You can set the height of the action bar at source not in the resources.

so all you need is to calculate the height of the action bar :

```
TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true))
{
    actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
Display d = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
d.getMetrics(dm);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)myCustomView.getLayoutParams();
final int ACTION_BAR_HEIGHT = dm.heightPixels/10; // 1/10 from screen height
lp.height = ACTION_BAR_HEIGHT;
myCustomView.setLayoutParams(lp);
bar.setCustomView(myCustomView);
```

Comment: what is currentAlbum in this?

Comment: edited, try this code. your actionbar's height will be 1/10 from screen size

Comment: Is 'myCustomView' a View?I mean what should i declare it?

Comment: Inflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);           myCustomView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar);